# ¿Cómo puedo llamar al dia posterior a una fecha determinada en Python?

Tags: python

Necesito que `since_date` sea un dia, y `until_date` sea el dia que le sigue siempre.
Yo lo había pensado de esta forma pero no está bien, no funciona.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
days = ['2019-10-16','2019-10-17', '2019-10-18','2019-10-19','2019-10-20','2019-10-21','2019-10-22','2019-10-23','2019-10-24','2019-10-25','2019-10-26','2019-10-27','2019-10-28','2019-10-29','2019-10-30','2019-10-31','2019-11-01','2019-11-02','2019-11-03','2019-11-04','2019-11-05','2019-11-06','2019-11-07','2019-11-08','2019-11-09','2019-11-10','2019-11-11','2019-11-12','2019-11-13','2019-11-14','2019-11-15','2019-11-16','2019-11-17','2019-11-18','2019-11-19','2019-11-20','2019-11-21','2019-11-22','2019-11-23','2019-11-24','2019-11-25','2019-11-26','2019-11-27','2019-11-28','2019-11-29','2019-11-30','2019-12-01','2019-12-02','2019-12-03','2019-12-04','2019-12-05','2019-12-06','2019-12-07','2019-12-07','2019-12-08','2019-12-09','2019-12-10','2019-12-11','2019-12-12','2019-12-13','2019-12-14','2019-12-15','2019-12-16','2019-12-17','2019-12-18','2019-12-19','2019-12-20','2019-12-21','2019-12-22','2019-12-23','2019-12-24','2019-12-25','2019-12-26','2019-12-27','2019-12-28','2019-12-29','2019-12-30','2019-12-31','2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05','2020-01-06','2020-01-07','2020-01-08','2020-01-09','2020-01-10','2020-01-11','2020-01-12','2020-01-13','2020-01-14','2020-01-15','2020-01-16','2020-01-17','2020-01-18','2020-01-19','2020-01-20','2020-01-21','2020-01-22','2020-01-23','2020-01-24','2020-01-25','2020-01-26']
for day in days:

        since_date = day

        until_date = (day + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No te funciona porque tal como lo tienes `day` es una cadena, y para sumarle un `timedelta()` necesitas que sea una fecha (o sea, un objeto de tipo `datetime`).

Usa `datetime.datetime.strptime(day, "%Y-%m-%d")` para convertirlo en fecha y así poder operar con él, por ejemplo:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# He acortado la lista de días, para el ejemplo es suficiente
days = ['2019-10-28','2019-10-29','2019-10-30','2019-10-31','2019-11-01']

for day in days:
    since_date = day
    until_date = (datetime.strptime(day, "%Y-%m-%d") 
                  + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print(since_date, "---", until_date)
```

El resultado es:

```
2019-10-28 --- 2019-10-29
2019-10-29 --- 2019-10-30
2019-10-30 --- 2019-10-31
2019-10-31 --- 2019-11-01
2019-11-01 --- 2019-11-02
```